# Can't Align ImageView in Table Cell in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

OK, here's ANOTHER question about positioning objects in tables in Android, but nothing I've found on Stack has helped.

I want the `ImageView` in the XML below to be left aligned in its cell.  No matter what I've tried, though, it won't do this (it's always centered).  The `layout_width` and `layout_weight` are set as they are to control the position and sizes of the cells themselves.  Maybe these settings are making it impossible to left align the `ImageView` in its cell, though.

`android:layout_gravity="left"` and `android:gravity="left"` didn't work in either the ImageView tag or the TableRow tag. One kind of kludgy solution that seems to work is to add a blank TextView in a third column, to force the 2nd column holding the ImageView to be exactly the width of the `ImageView`'s bitmap.  However, I'd prefer not to have to do this, especially since different rows may contain bitmaps of different widths.

```
<TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/scoreTable"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

     <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/thisWeek"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/thisWeekText"
             android:layout_width="0px"
             android:layout_height="30dp"
             android:layout_weight="35"
             android:gravity="right"
             android:paddingRight="30px"
             android:text="@string/thisWeek"
             android:textStyle="bold" />


         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/chevron1"
             android:layout_width="0px"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:layout_weight="65"
             android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
             android:src="@drawable/doser_scale4a"
             android:visibility="visible" />


     </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the TextViews with ImageViews, using bitmaps of the text that was in the TextViews.  This was OK for me because that text won't be changing, though I guess if it did I could create images for all possible text and switch between those images.

This was not an ideal solution, since I assume using bitmaps instead of text uses more memory, and making bitmaps for my text required a little time and effort and some sacrifice of ease and flexibility of changing the text, if that is desired at some point, but I couldn't figure out how to make this work with TextViews.  Android definitely seems limited in this way, since it shouldn't be that difficult to align text any way you want in a table cell, should it?

Answer (score 0):

Each "cell" of the TableRow is a View, so you could put a LinearLayout (with your preferred gravity) and put inside this LinearLayour your image.